# Grid traveller: Find maximum score while satisfying a constraint using dynamic programming

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic, dynamic-programming

Assume we have a `9 x 9` grid with integer values at each cell. A traveler begins at any column of his preference in the first row. Each turn, he goes either down, down-left, or down-right. This is, if `(i, j)` is his current position, he can choose to go `(i+1, j-1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j+1)`. He continues until he arrives to the last row. On each step, he adds to his score the value of the cell he goes to.

Our task is to find the maximum possible score he can obtain while satisfying the following constraint: He cannot travel to a cell if his score plus the value of such cell is negative. For example, in a `3x3` case,

```
1   2   3
3   4   -4
-2  2   4
```

If he starts in the first row on the `3`, he cannot travell to the cell `-4` because `3 - 4 < 0`.

A recursive solution in Python looks as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

BOARD = [[random.randint(-9, 9) for _ in range(9)] for _ in range(9)]
def traveller_rec(i, j, s):

    n = len(BOARD[1])
    if  j < 0 or j >= n:
        return(np.NINF)
    if i != 0 and s + BOARD[i][j] < 0: # Player is allowed to begin at a negative-valued cell
        return(np.NINF)
    
    if i == n - 1:
        return(BOARD[i][j]) if BOARD[i][j] > 0 else np.NINF

    return max(
            BOARD[i][j] + traveller_rec(i + 1, j, s + BOARD[i][j]),
            BOARD[i][j] + traveller_rec(i + 1, j + 1, s + BOARD[i][j]),
            BOARD[i][j] + traveller_rec(i + 1, j - 1, s + BOARD[i][j])
            )
```

For example, `traveller_rec(0, 5, 0)` gives the maximum possible score starting at column index `5`.

However, I have completely failed in implementing a dynamic solution. I am particularly interested in using tabulation (not memoization) for such solution. How could one solve this problem using dynamic programing?

Comment: Can you share your attempted bottom up solution?